# List all channels available in SendBird Application

Tags: swift, api, swift3, sendbird

Is there a way to list all available Open Channel/Group in a specific application using the SendBird API. I was able to find functions that create a channel, and delete a channel, but not list all the available channels in a specific app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a v3 answer-only...

To list all available open channels, for example, use something like this:

```
OpenChannelListQuery clq = OpenChannel.createOpenChannelListQuery();          
clq.next(new OpenChannelListQuery.OpenChannelListQueryResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(List<OpenChannel> list, SendBirdException e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"query results, "+list.size()+" open channels");
        }
});
```

Remember that you need the connection to be completed before invoking the above.

Comment: https://docs.sendbird.com/platform/open_channel#3_list_channels

Comment: @Andy Do you have any idea to retrieve all the public group channels?. I tried to retrieve using createPublicGroupChannelListQuery() but I am getting a null object though there are some few public group channels. Your help would be really appreciated!!